# How to debug C# code using Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am a newbie to VS Code environment. I am developing a Web API in VS Code which would later be consumed from client application. Following code block does not seem to be executing so I want to check whether it is at all hitting!

```html
//GET: pwapi/plants/10076/features
[HttpGet("{id}, {sectionArray}")]
public async Task<string> Get(int id, string sectionArray){
  var url="https://www.domain.com/search?apikey=<apikey>&sections="+sectionArray+"&plantid="+id;
   
  using(var client = new HttpClient()){
    client.BaseAddress=new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    var response=await client.GetAsync(url);
    
    //will throw an exception if not successful
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
    //return await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Parse(content));
    return content;
  }
}
```

URL for the above method is http://localhost:5000/pwapi/plants/10076/features

I have the overloaded method which is working fine:

```html
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<string> Get(int id){
  var url="https://www.domain.com/list?apikey=<apikey>";
  using(var client = new HttpClient()){
    client.BaseAddress=new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    var response=await client.GetAsync(url);
    
    //will throw an exception if not successful
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
    //return await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Parse(content));
    return content;
  }
}
```

URL for the above method is `http://localhost:5000/pwapi/plants/10076`

Three questions:
1. How I can debug the code?
2. If debug is not possible (so far I have seen that debug is possible for client scripts only, I may be wrong), what is the alternative way to know where I am doing wrong?
3. If there is no alternative, please tell me why the method is not hitting.

Comment: which version of webapi you are using? Did you defined a route for multiple parameters? When you look for the endpoint in browser do you get a 404 response code? and also you need to append api in front of you api controllers. Please let me know. I think appending API infront of pwapi should should solve the issue.

Comment: not sure about webapi version. I am developing in asp.net 5 using dnx. there is no typical 404, but a blank screen is appearing. `http://localhost:5000/pwapi/plants/10076` works fine without appending anything but `http://localhost:5000/pwapi/plants/10076/features` doesn't. **"Did you defined a route for multiple parameters"** - how can I do this? I am a newbie! :)

Comment: why there is a comma in your route prefix? [HttpGet("{id}, {sectionArray}")] Try using [HttpGet("{id}/{sectionArray}")]

Comment: solution worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! however I would still like to know about debugging c# in VS code. And here is the route `[Route("pwapi/[controller]")]`.

Comment: Okay I will write an answer and will write the steps too.

Answer (score 2):

If you notice your route prefix for Get overload you have a comma instead of a slash, which makes the route invalid therefore your endpoint never gets hit. Please change the route prefix to this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/{sectionArray}")]
```

As for debugging the endpoint you just need to put a break point by either pressing F9 on the line or by clicking on the left of the line of code that you want to debug.

Comment: Yes, as for debugging I already used the steps you mentioned above. This creates an empty `launch.json` but it needs additional `configurations` to set in order to initiate the debugging process. Where I can get the configurations?

Comment: can I see the content of launch.json file? If you need to attach to some process that will be "w3wp.exe" for asp.net hosted sites/apis

Comment: I updated VS Code. Now launch.json has something in it. However, `"program"` node is set to `"ConsoleApplication.exe"` but mine is a Web API.

Comment: Instead of consileapplicatikn.exe use w3wp.exe

Comment: `request 'launch': program 'd:\Projects\aspnet\apiservice\w3wp.exe' does not exist`. Do I have to install debugger using locally for this project? If yes how? I have asp.net 5 installed already. Won't VS Code use it from GAC?

Comment: Actually you gave to attach your code with IIS process which is called w3wp.exe. did u try manually attach it manually. You may be able to do that from debug->attach to process -> the find process that's running your iis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99134/discussion-between-niladri-sarkar-and-qamar).